# How to use multiples Parse instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parse-server

Is there a way to initialize multiple parse apps in react javascript, currently i am initializing single parse app like this

```
Parse.initialize(config.appId);
Parse.serverURL = config.serverURL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently with the implementation of the SDK you cannot do that. Theses methods and properties are static as you can see [here](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.1.0/Parse.html)

What you can do is to use the [REST API](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/)

You can also suggest this feature on the GitHub repository